# TableSorter Math and External Widget

Tags: tablesorter

I am trying to use the math widget on a table already using an external filter with dates.
When i include math widget it only filters the sum calculated and leaves the elements of the table as is.
I believe it might be targeting only the math row due to data-column=0 filter.

```
 {widthFixed: true, sortList: [[0, 0]], widgets: ['zebra', 'filter','math'],
               widgetOptions: {

                   filter_external: '.search',
                   // add a default type search to the first name column
                   filter_defaultFilter: { 1: '~{query}' },
                   // include column filters
                   filter_columnFilters: false,
                   filter_placeholder: { search: 'Search...' },
                   filter_filteredRow: 'filtered',
                   filter_saveFilters: false,
                   filter_reset: '.reset',
                   math_data: 'math', // data-math attribute
                   math_ignore: [0],
                   math_complete: function ($cell, wo, result, value, arry) {
                       var txt = '<span class="align-decimal">$ ' + result + '</span>';
                       if ($cell.attr('data-math') === 'all-sum') {
                           // when the "all-sum" is processed, add a count to the end
                           return txt + ' (Sum of ' + arry.length + ' Days)';
                       }
                       return txt;
                   }
               }
           })
           .tablesorterPager({ container: $("#pager"), positionFixed: false });
        $("#from").datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            dateFormat: 'd MM yy',
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
                setTimeout(function () { updateFilters(); }, 1);
            }
        });
        $("#to").datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
                setTimeout(function () { updateFilters(); }, 1);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you provide a demo? Also, the `positionFixed` pager option was only available in the original pager addon; are you using the most up-to-date code from the [FORK of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/)?

Comment: yes this isn't the updated code but i get same results when i had updated libraries. And i am using the FORK.

Comment: This is not exactly the same working code as i am working on vb.net.
But the way this works is i have a date range taken between to and from.
Filters work perfectly as needed when i don't use the math widget.
But when i include math,it will just filter the above-sum and not the table values.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/o0ygngr5/

Comment: If you could provide me with a basic working example,i can work on it.
Thanks

Comment: Also i am using jquery datepicker and paging which i havent included in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your demo to make the date pickers work with the filter widget ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/o0ygngr5/1/))

Is that what you wanted?

```
$(function () {
    var $table = $('.tablesorter'),
        validDate = function (d) {
            return d instanceof Date && isFinite(d);
        },
        updateFilters = function () {
            var filter = '',
                from = $('#from').datepicker('getDate') || '',
                to = $('#to').datepicker('getDate') || '';
            if (from && to) {
                filter = from.getTime() + ' - ' + to.getTime();
            } else if (from && !to) {
                filter = '>=' + from.getTime();
            } else if (!from && to) {
                filter = '<=' + to.getTime();
            }
            console.log(filter);
            $.tablesorter.setFilters($table, [filter], true);
        };
    $table.tablesorter({
        // include zebra and any other widgets, options:
        // 'columns', 'filter', 'stickyHeaders' & 'resizable'
        // 'uitheme' is another widget, but requires loading
        // a different skin and a jQuery UI theme.
        widgets: ['zebra', 'filter', 'math'],

        // filter_external: '.search',
        // add a default type search to the first name column
        filter_defaultFilter: {
            1: '~{query}'
        },
        // include column filters
        filter_columnFilters: false,
        filter_saveFilters: false,
        filter_reset: '.reset',
        math_data: 'math', // data-math attribute
        math_ignore: [0],
        math_complete: function ($cell, wo, result, value, arry) {
            var txt = '<center>$ ' + result + '</center>';
            return txt;
        },

        initialized: function (table) {
            // target select
            var i, o, select = $(table).find('select.tablesorter-filter');
            $('button').click(function () {
                i = $(this).data('index');
                select[0].options[i].selected = true;
                select.trigger('change');
            });
        }

    });
    $("#from").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "2015-05-01",
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
            setTimeout(function () {
                updateFilters();
            }, 1);
        }
    });
    $("#to").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "2015-05-30",
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
            setTimeout(function () {
                updateFilters();
            }, 1);
        }
    });


});
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: although this works perfectly in JSFiddle,on my end its not disabling column filters. But i can do with that just by hiding the .tablesorter-filter-row.

Comment: and in the demo its not applying the changes in the math_complete : function.
The center align.

Comment: [Don't use `<center>`, the tag has been deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center), instead, if you are using the [`math_mask` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-math.html#math_mask), then everything should line up if you use `text-align: right` in the css for that column: `tr td:nth-child(1) { text-align: right}`